# JavaFX tableview Enable and Disable row selection

Tags: javafx, tableview

As a part of my project i want display a tableview which should be disabled for some time(on editting time nb:not table editting).So that i got a working code which will disable the tableview.This is the working code,

```
table.setSelectionModel(null);
```

So my problem is after editing process is over when click a button i want to enable it back,but unfortunately i could'nt find any alternative code for that.Any one please suggest me the code which will enable the row selection.Any answer will appreciable.

Comment: Why not just do `table.setDisable(true);` and `table.setDisable(false)`, as needed?

Comment: i dont want disable the table i want disable row selection

Comment: And that code table.setSelectionModel(null); is working correctly for disabling row selection,but i need the alternative code to enable it back thats all.

Comment: OK; can you [edit] your question then? It says: "i want display a tableview *which should be disabled for some time*". You can just retrieve the selection model after creating the table: see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the default selection model when you create the table:

```
TableView<T> table = new TableView<>();
TableViewSelectionModel<T> defaultSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();
```

where `T` is the type for your table. (Of course, if you are using FXML, just put the second line in the controller's `initialize()` method.)

Then to disable row selection do

```
table.setSelectionModel(null);
```

and to enable it again

```
table.setSelectionModel(defaultSelectionModel);
```

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableWithDisabledSelection extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        TableViewSelectionModel<Person> defaultSelectionModel = table.getSelectionModel();

        table.getColumns().add(column("First Name", Person::firstNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Last Name", Person::lastNameProperty));
        table.getColumns().add(column("Email", Person::emailProperty));

        table.getItems().addAll(
                new Person("Jacob", "Smith", "jacob.smith@example.com"),
                new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", "isabella.johnson@example.com"),
                new Person("Ethan", "Williams", "ethan.williams@example.com"),
                new Person("Emma", "Jones", "emma.jones@example.com"),
                new Person("Michael", "Brown", "michael.brown@example.com") 
        );

        CheckBox enableSelection = new CheckBox("Enable selection");
        enableSelection.setSelected(true);
        enableSelection.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasSelected, isNowSelected) -> {

            if (isNowSelected) {
                table.setSelectionModel(defaultSelectionModel);
            } else {
                table.setSelectionModel(null);
            }


        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(enableSelection, Pos.CENTER);
        BorderPane.setMargin(enableSelection, new Insets(5));
        root.setBottom(enableSelection);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private <S,T> TableColumn<S,T> column(String title, Function<S,Property<T>> prop) {
        TableColumn<S,T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> prop.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        return col ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty lastName = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private final StringProperty email = new SimpleStringProperty();

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
            setFirstName(firstName);
            setLastName(lastName);
            setEmail(email);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }


        public final String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setFirstName(final String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }


        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }


        public final String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setLastName(final String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }


        public final StringProperty emailProperty() {
            return this.email;
        }


        public final String getEmail() {
            return this.emailProperty().get();
        }


        public final void setEmail(final String email) {
            this.emailProperty().set(email);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: yes,this is the code which i expected but unfortunately its not working brother.still in disabled mode

Comment: @AchuRockzz It works just fine for me: I added a complete example (using a checkbox to enable/disable row selection). If it doesn't work for you, you have something else wrong somewhere.

Comment: wow sorry,first i put the code inside the button event,now it's works perfectly when i put the second line under initialize() method.James_D rockzz..

Answer (score 1):

I handled this situation with rowfactory like this;

```
tableView.setRowFactory(param -> new TableRow<Model>()
{
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Model item, boolean empty)
    {
       super.updateItem(item, empty);
       if (!empty)
       {
           disableProperty().bind(item.getFocusable().not());
       }
    }
});
```

so, you can bind the disableproperty with suitable property of your tableview model.

Comment: What does the object you fill the table look like? I mean, you need a property which is defined BooleanProperty type. In my example code I have a property that was not written like this; private BooleanProperty focusable; also i have getters and setters. So in example code i have used  this getter; public BooleanProperty getFocusable()
    {
        return focusable;
    } Please try again with this approach.